# I need help in using the logical operators with sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm building "Advanced Search."
Where we use "OR," "AND," "AND NOT."
Where you can search for many columns using the mentioned operators.
I have already built most of the project. But I'm facing an issue with the sequelize.

To save time, what I am trying to do is generate this where closure using sequelize ORM

```
WHERE 
  (
    "materials"."main_category" = 'Publication' 
    AND "materials"."is_active" = true 
    AND "materials"."is_restricted" = false 
    AND 
      (
      "materials"."pub_subjects_ar" ='value1'
    OR
      "materials"."pub_subjects_ar" = 'value2'
    AND
      "materials"."pub_entries_ar" = 'value2'
    OR
      "materials"."pub_entries_ar" = 'value3'
  )
  )
```

any suggestion or hints ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use operators available as Symbols from `Op`.

```js
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

// Replace model name and find method as per your requirements
Materials.findAll({
    // ... attributes
    where: {
        main_category: 'Publication',
        is_active: true,
        is_restricted: false,
        [Op.or]: {
            pub_subjects_ar: value1,
            pub_subjects_ar: value2
        },
        [Op.or]: {
            pub_entries_ar: value2,
            pub_entries_ar: value3
        }
    }
})
```

The comparison in the innermost parenthesis is not clear in your question, so I have taken the liberty of assuming that you're trying to do the following:

```sql
(
  "materials"."pub_subjects_ar" ='value1'
  OR
  "materials"."pub_subjects_ar" = 'value2'
)
AND
(
  "materials"."pub_entries_ar" = 'value2'
  OR
  "materials"."pub_entries_ar" = 'value3'
)
```